# Second order ODE general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 2\frac{dy}{dx} + y = x^2e^x$

I need to find a general solution.

I am able to get by using the characteristic equation that λ = 1 is a 2-multiple solution so in the homogenous case, $y = c_1e^x + c_2xe^x$

but that is not the final answer as I still have to consider the non-homogenous case which is what I don't quite know how to do... Could someone show me?

Comment: so for the final answer I got $y = c_1e^x + c_2xe^x + (\frac{1}{4}x^2 + \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{3}{8})e^x$ could somebody tell me if that is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, Let $u = y' - y$, then $u' = y'' - y'$. So: $u' - u = x^2e^x$ and you can use the theory about first order ODE to finish it in $u$, and then in $x$.